# get specific lines with grep

Tags: grep

I would like to parse a text like that:

```
# cmd: Text_finder --outdir 1
# No Text found
# cmd: Text_finder --outdir 2
ID_Text ID element  pos_beg pos_end model   type    default distance
Text_01 tt  001 38  108 1   6.3e-05     No
Text_01 tt  002 454 517 1   1.9e-05     No
Text_01 tt_c7   003 1276    1362    1   2.2e-08     No
# cmd: Text_finder --outdir 3
# No Text found
# cmd: Text_finder --outdir 4
# No Text found
# cmd: Text_finder --outdir 5
ID_Text ID element  pos_beg pos_end model   type    default distance
Text_01 tt  001 38  108 1   6.3e-05     No
```

in order to retrieve lines starting with "Text_01" (results), "ID_Text" (headline) but also line before "ID_Text" (starting with "# cmd:" but also common to the line with no result I want to get ride off).

I have tried to combine and execute these lines:

```
#get lines with "ID_text" and "text_01"
grep -P "ID_text|text_01" result.txt > positive-results.txt;

#get line before line with "ID_text" 
grep -B1 "ID_text" result.txt > positive-results.txt;
```

but I cannot get a file like that:

```
# cmd: Text_finder --outdir 2
ID_Text ID element  pos_beg pos_end model   type    default distance
Text_01 tt  001 38  108 1   6.3e-05     No
Text_01 tt  002 454 517 1   1.9e-05     No
Text_01 tt_c7   003 1276    1362    1   2.2e-08     No
# cmd: Text_finder --outdir 5
ID_Text ID element  pos_beg pos_end model   type    default distance
Text_01 tt  001 38  108 1   6.3e-05     No
```

Do you have a smart way to do that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ grep --no-group-separator -B 1 "^\(Text_01\|ID_Text\)" file
```

Output:

```
# cmd: Text_finder --outdir 2
ID_Text ID element  pos_beg pos_end model   type    default distance
Text_01 tt  001 38  108 1   6.3e-05     No
Text_01 tt  002 454 517 1   1.9e-05     No
Text_01 tt_c7   003 1276    1362    1   2.2e-08     No
# cmd: Text_finder --outdir 5
ID_Text ID element  pos_beg pos_end model   type    default distance
Text_01 tt  001 38  108 1   6.3e-05     No
```

`man grep`:

```
-B NUM, --before-context=NUM
          Print NUM  lines  of  leading  context  before  matching  lines.
          Places   a  line  containing  a  group  separator  (--)  between
          contiguous groups of matches.
```

Interestingly my man page has no explanation for `--no-group-separator` but try above once without it and you'll see.

Comment: it works perfectly, thanks! I had no idea about '--no-group-separator'

Comment: "_Interestingly my man page has no explanation for --no-group-separator_": it is apparently the kind of rarely used features that are documented in the `Texinfo` documentation but not in the `man` page.